# How can I trigger actions in my JPA mapped classes whenever they are saved to the database?

Tags: jpa

I want to have a function in one of my JPA annotated classes that is called every time the EntityManager saves them to the database (aka event listener). Is that possible? Preferably, I'd like to distinguish whether it is just about to be saved or has just been saved.

To accomplish what I want, this time I could probably work around with a setter method, but it wouldn't be quite the same.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sure, check out [these examples](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0355__JPA/EntityListenerPreUpdate.htm). You have:

- `@PrePersist`;
- `@PreUpdate`;
- `@PreRemove`.
- `@PostPersist`;
- `@PostUpdate`; and
- `@PostRemove`.

*(added by Hanno) - Using this answer for starters, I also found [this other nice example tutorial](http://mikedesjardins.us/wordpress/2008/03/pizza-shop-iii-jpa-event-listeners/).*

Comment: Hello, I cannot open the first link, the second links seems is not the correct one. can you give me an example code?

Answer (score 1):

This may be irrelevant now, since this thread is a few years old, but I think the tutorial Hanno is referring to is on this other (working) link:

http://www.cereslogic.com/pages/2008/03/31/pizza-shop-iii-jpa-event-listeners/

And there is also another helpful tutorial on this subject here:

http://www.andygibson.net/blog/article/auditing-entities-with-jpa-events/

I thought I contribute with something to the people who may find this thread in the future.

Saludos desde Bolivia

Comment: +1 for useful information. (It may have been more appropriate as a _comment_ to the other answer, rather than a new answer since it doesn't really answer the question.)